# Computing the eth root in Z(N)* i.e set of all elements coprime to N

Tags: number-theory

I understand that it is easy to compute eth root in Z(P)* but what about with Z(N)*? I know that it requires the factorization of N but what does that actually mean? What is an example of calculating the eth root in the set Z(N)* (the set of all elements coprime to N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that it requires the factorization of N but what does that actually mean?

I means pretty much what it say on the tin - we don't know a way of efficiently computing the $e$-th root of a value $x$ modulo a value $N$ without the full factorization of $N$ (and a partial factorization of $N$, such as $N = p \cdot q \cdot c.$ where $c$ is a large composite, doesn't help).  That is, we don't know a practical way of finding $y$ s.t. $y^e \equiv x \pmod N$.

In fact, this problem is known as the *RSA problem*; that is, if you can solve it, you've broken RSA.

> What is an example of calculating the eth root in the set Z(N) (the set of all elements coprime to N)

If you do know the factorization of $N = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} ... p_n^{e_n}$ where $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ are prime, then it is easy:

For each $p_i^{e_i}$, solve the problem $y_i^e \equiv x \pmod {p_i^{e_i}}$ (and if there is an $i$ where there isn't a solution, there's no solution for the overall problem).  You already know how to solve it for $e_i=1$; solving it for $e_i > 1$ isn't that much more difficult.

Once you have all the $y_i$ values, use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine them into a $y$ value - that's your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also,if $e$ is coprime to $\varphi(n),$ then we can compute $m = 1÷e$ (mod $\varphi(n)$).

And so for every $a$ coprime to $n,$ we get $$(a^m)^e = a.$$

I.e. $a^m$ is the $e^{th}$ root of $a.$